# HTML - inner rounded 2 elements

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I've been looking around but could not find a way t do "inner" rounded corners in a "L" like element

Currently I have something like the following:

```css
#container {
  width: 800px;
  display: block;
  background: white;
}
#a {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 2px;
}
#b {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 2px 2px 2px 14px;
  margin: 2px 2px 2px -8px;
}
#c {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  float: right;
  width: calc(100% - 166px);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="a">
    WWWWWWWWWWWW
    <br/>WWWWWWWWWWWW
    <br/>WWWWWWWWWWWW
    <br/>
  </div>
  <div id="b">
    MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
    <br/>MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
  </div>
  <div id="c">
    OOOOOOOOOOOO
    <br/>OOOOOOOOOOOO
    <br/>OOOOOOOOOOOO
    <br/>OOOOOOOOOOOO
    <br/>OOOOOOOOOOOO
    <br/>OOOOOOOOOOOO
    <br/>OOOOOOOOOOOO
    <br/>OOOOOOOOOOOO
    <br/>OOOOOOOOOOOO
    <br/>OOOOOOOOOOOO
    <br/>OOOOOOOOOOOO
    <br/>OOOOOOOOOOOO
    <br/>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Problem comes that the "inner corner" is 90º and I want a rounded corner, is there any way to accomplish that 90º angle to be rounded like the rest?

Have to keep in mind that all background colours/image can change (`#a` and `#b` will always share the same colour) and all text lengths are variable so `#a` can have less or equal lines than `#b`.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

And is there any way to remove the `<div style="clear:both"></div>` and have the container to keep all elements inside or is something absolutely necessary?

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you are trying to do but I **think** you're trying to have two divs that are **touching** appear to flow into one another with a radiused corner on the **outside** of the join...is that it? An **image** here would be ideal.

Comment: modified a bit the code so it can be run without full page mode, there you can see that there is a 90 degree angle within element a and b and what I want is to make it rounded

Comment: Here's one idea [**Round Out Borders**](https://css-tricks.com/tabs-with-round-out-borders/)

Comment: the link one uses a trick with a square and a circle colouring the square with the place he wants tote be rounded and the circle to colour the "outer" place, this won't for what I posted since the background (`#container`) can be a single colour or an image

Comment: Then you're out of luck...CSS can't do this.. **yet**

Comment: Then using a small SVG image for that particular rounded border, instead of the square and circle as in the example @Paulie_D referred to, might be able to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Little hacky method using of `box-shadow` for `#c` and pseudo element for `#b` for adding `right` side curved

```css
#container {
  width: 800px;
  display: block;
  background: white;
}
#a {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 2px;
}
#b {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 2px 2px 8px 14px;
  margin: 2px 2px 2px -8px;
  position: relative;
}
#b:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 7px;
  right: -6px;
  width: 10px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
#c {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  float: right;
  width: calc(100% - 166px);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 4px green;
  position: relative;
  top: -7px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="a">
    WWWWWWWWWWWW
    <br/>WWWWWWWWWWWW
    <br/>WWWWWWWWWWWW
    <br/>
  </div>
  <div id="b">
    MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
    <br/>MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
  </div>
  <div id="c">
    OOOOOOOOOOOO
    <br/>OOOOOOOOOOOO
    <br/>OOOOOOOOOOOO
    <br/>OOOOOOOOOOOO
    <br/>OOOOOOOOOOOO
    <br/>OOOOOOOOOOOO
    <br/>OOOOOOOOOOOO
    <br/>OOOOOOOOOOOO
    <br/>OOOOOOOOOOOO
    <br/>OOOOOOOOOOOO
    <br/>OOOOOOOOOOOO
    <br/>OOOOOOOOOOOO
    <br/>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: not exactly what I was looking but I suppose I'll use a trick like this one (seems simpler than the sphere ones) and was more or less the original idea I had (but it doesn't allow having a background image)